# Definition List creation

Tags: xml, xslt

Trying to create a definition list in my XML using XSLT.

Here is an illustration of what my input looks like:

```
  <p>

    <i>word1</i> definition text here <br />
    <br />
       <i>word1</i> definition text here <br />
    <br />
       <i>word1</i> definition text here <br />
    <br />
       <i>word1</i> definition text here <br />
    <br />
       <i>word1</i> definition text here <br />

</p>
```

the "definition text here" in the above XML are un-tagged text nodes that I want to tag and include in my output. 
An illustration of the output I want is below:

```
<dl>
   <di>
      <dt>word1</dt>
      <dd>definition text here<dd>
   <di>
<dl>
```

My template so far that is not working:

```
<xsl:template match="p">

        <dl>
             <dt>
                <xsl:value-of select="./i/node()"/>
            </dt>

             <dd>
              <xsl:sequence select="./text()" />
            </dd>
        </dl>

    </xsl:template>
```

Anyone know a quick and easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="p">
     <dl>
       <di><xsl:apply-templates/></di>
     </dl>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="i">
  <dt><xsl:value-of select="."/></dt>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::i]]">
  <dd><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/></dd>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (it was severely malformed -- corrected here):

```
<p>
    <i>word1</i> definition text here 
    <br />
    <br />
    <i>word2</i> definition text here
    <br />
    <br />
    <i>word3</i> definition text here
    <br />
    <br />
    <i>word4</i> definition text here
    <br />
    <br />
    <i>word5</i> definition text here
    <br />
</p>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<dl>
   <di>
      <dt>word1</dt>
      <dd>definition text here</dd>
      <dt>word2</dt>
      <dd>definition text here</dd>
      <dt>word3</dt>
      <dd>definition text here</dd>
      <dt>word4</dt>
      <dd>definition text here</dd>
      <dt>word5</dt>
      <dd>definition text here</dd>
   </di>
</dl>
```

**and it displays in the browser as**:

word1

definition text here

word2

definition text here

word3

definition text here

word4

definition text here

word5

definition text here

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dimitre, sorry about the malformed input. That is really what my input document looks like as I am dealing with some very poorly marked up html as my input.

Comment: @Laterade, Oh, that's OK. Was my answer useful to you?

Comment: Yes, however my text nodes are not getting picked up. It is catching each <i> and putting it in a <dt> but your template for text() is not matching for some reason. Also, I would like now to next <dd> inside of <dt>, is there any easy tweak to your code to where I can do this?

Comment: @Laterade, I always verify that the code really produces the wanted result -- typically I copy the result of the transformation and paste it into the answer. The reason you aren't getting the same result might be one of these: 1. You have changed the source XML document; 2. You have changed the transformation code; 3. Both 1 and 2; 4. You are using a non-compliant/buggy XSLT processor. Please, find which of these four possibilities are true in your case, and correct them. As for answering other questions -- I would be glad to answer them -- please, *ask* a new question.

Comment: Yes the input document I am using is a little different which is the issue. I had to dumb it down because my input doc is very convoluted with terrible html. You have given me a great starting point though, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to emit one `di` element for each `i` in the input, not one for each `p` in the input.  So first of all, move your code to a template for `i`.

In your input, each `i` is immediately followed by a single text node containing the text to be tagged as `dd`.  This has to be embedded within the `di` element, so it needs to be handled within the template for `i`, something like this (not tested):

```
<xsl:template match='i'>
  <di>
    <dt><xsl:value-of select="."/></dt>
    <dd><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::text()[1]"/></dd>
  </di>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p/text() | p/br"/>
```

If some definitions have embedded markup, you'll need a more complicated way to populate the `dd` element, but sufficient unto the day is the evil thereof.  You asked for something quick and easy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wasn't able to incorporate this into my stylesheet =(. My input is different than what I posted in my question, and I wasn't able to get it working with my input file. Thanks for the reply though.